# Handling MaxUploadSizeExceededException in Spring webapp

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, multipartform-data

I'm trying to handle maximum upload size exception but all solutions i found failed, I tried implementing `HandlerExceptionResolver`, `@ControllerAdvice` and method annotated by `@ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)` but nothning helped.
Among the answers to similar questions i found out that it could be because the exception is thrown before the controller is even called but i don't have such insight into this issue so i can't solve it on my own. 
 
Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size of 500000 bytes exceeded; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (1065736) exceeds the configured maximum (500000)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:139)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (1065736) exceeds the configured maximum (500000)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:965)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:334)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:156)
    ... 20 more
```

and some parts of my code that handle Multipart resolving and so on ... 
SecurityWebAppInitializer.class - I suspect this MultipartFilter might be part of the problem but it has to be there because of this http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-multipartfilter

```
@Order(1)
public class SecurityWebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
    }

}
```

Multipart Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class MultipartConfig {

    @Bean 
    public MultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        filterMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000);

        return filterMultipartResolver;
    }        
}
```

WebAppInitializer.class

```
@Order(2)
public class WebAppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {MultipartConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { DispatcherConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter};
    }

}
```

If you need some other parts of webapp just ask.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This one will help u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856254/how-to-nicely-handle-file-upload-maxuploadsizeexceededexception-with-spring-secu

Answer (score 1):

if you do not know max upload size then don't set the max upload size.
If you want to restrict the MAX upload size then you need to consider otherwise comment it
Below I have commented the setter to set max upload size.

```
@Configuration
public class MultipartConfig {

    @Bean 
    public MultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        //filterMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000);

        return filterMultipartResolver;
    }        
}
```

Comment: also a solution :D thanks god i'm making just example webapp. Anyway, if someone finds a solution with max upload size set, i would very much like to see it :)

Answer (score 0):

I captured it by this class:

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionHandlerController implements ErrorController, HandlerExceptionResolver{
private static final String PATH = "/error";

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionHandlerController.class);

public String getErrorPath() {
    return PATH;
}

@Override
public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest arg0,
HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception exception) {
    log.debug("Captured....");
    Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    //all the exception is here and u can specified it by this exception: MaxUploadSizeExceededException
    return new ModelAndView("Error", (Map) model);
}
}
```

I used SpringBoot, so it require me to implements ErrorController. If you don't then do not need to implement it.

Hope it help for someone looking for this situation.