# Java/Spring MaxUploadSizeExceededException post parameters

Tags: java, spring, validation, exception

I have a form with a three text fields and a file upload field.
When I reach the MaxUploadSizeExceededException exception I can handle with a class that implements HandlerExceptionResolver.
I have my custom handler class with

```
resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception){ ... }
```

My problem is that I need a way to pass some variables to Exception handler (the values of other fields in the form) so I can return a ModelAndView that contains these variables. I don't want to redirect to an error page, I want to return to my Form, without losing inserted values.

I've also a "Validator" that validates other fields and it works, but I don't know how to integrate it with MaxUploadSizeExceededException exception.

My controller implements HandlerExceptionResolver

```
@Override
public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception)
{        
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    if (exception instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException)
    {
        // this is empty!
        Map<String,String[]> paramMap = request.getParameterMap();

        // model.put("ticketForm", new TicketForm());
        // ticketForm.setId();

        model.put("err", exception.getMessage());
        return new ModelAndView(inserisciticket", model);
    } else
    {
        model.put("err", "Unexpected error: " + exception.getMessage());
        return new ModelAndView("error", model);
    }
}
```

This is the function that is called from the form:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/inseriscinuovoticket", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String inseriscinuovoticket(
        @RequestParam(value = "idArgomento", required = true, defaultValue = "") String idArgomento,
        @RequestParam(value = "oggetto", required = true, defaultValue = "") String oggetto,
        @RequestParam(value = "descrizione", required = true, defaultValue = "") String descrizione,
        @RequestParam(value = "fileuploaded", required = false) MultipartFile fileuploaded,
        @ModelAttribute("ticket") TicketForm ticketForm, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
        Locale locale) throws IOException  { .... }
```

Can you help me?

------------- EDIT 2 --------------------

I tried the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856254/how-to-nicely-handle-file-upload-maxuploadsizeexceededexception-with-spring-secu)

```
public class MultipartExceptionHandler extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (MaxUploadSizeExceededException e) {
        handle(request, response, e);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        if(e.getRootCause() instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException) {
            handle(request, response, (MaxUploadSizeExceededException) e.getRootCause());
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

private void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, MaxUploadSizeExceededException e) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // null
    TicketForm t = (TicketForm)request.getAttribute("ticket");
    // null
    String idArgomento = (String)request.getAttribute("idArgomento");

    response.sendRedirect("inserisciticket");
  }
}
```

But also in the handle and in the filter I CAN'T read form parameters (post data).
How can I do???

Thank you.

Comment: Why you don't want to get parameters from `HttpServlerRequest`?

Comment: I tried but I can't see nothing. With  request.getParameterMap() I get an empty map.

Comment: please add code that you tried.

Comment: I posted the code down

Comment: please edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Probably you can use another way of handling this problem - [please see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856254/how-to-nicely-handle-file-upload-maxuploadsizeexceededexception-with-spring-secu)

Comment: Ok, i follow your link, but the problem persists. When my filter handle the exception I can't see the parameters from the submitted form. Why?
So if I make a redirect to my form page, other fields are reset.

Comment: It seems that the CommonsMultipartResolver when throw the exception caused by file too big, stop the parameters parsing.
This is why in the request object I haven't parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The following changes resolved the fileUpload size issues(MaxUploadSizeExceededException) in my application. 
Do the following changes in "application.yml" to fix this issue.  Setting -1 means, unlimited size allowed.

Spring:
   servlet:
      multipart:
          max-file-size: -1

Spring:
   servlet:
      multipart:
          max-request-size: -1